How do I transfer variables from the function to the thread?
For some reason this code throws me an error:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.BeginUpdate();
    TreeNode labelnode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Label" + labelnum.ToString());
    treeView1.EndUpdate();

    //create id
    string id = "1";

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Worker(labelnode, id))); // it errors out here
    thread.Start();
}

private void Worker(TreeNode labelnode, string id)
{ 
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        if (labelnode.IsSelected == true)
        {
            showProperties("label", id);
        }
    }
}

What I was trying to do here is show properties when labelnode was selected. Would be glad and thankful if someone helped me.

try separating your business logic from your presentation

You can't modify UI components from another thread in any OS. What are you actually trying to do? Most likely you can change this code into asynchronous code that performs whatever is needed in the background then gets back to the UI thread to update it, eg await Task.Delay(someSensibleDelay); await Task.Run(someHeavyJob);  labelNode.Text="Tada!";

On the other hand, using a busy loop to check for node selection is extremely expensive and will peg a core at 100% doing essentially nothing. Use the TreeView.AfterSelect or BeforeSelect events instead

It seems that what the code is trying to do is check whether a node is selected. The proper way to do this is to use the TreeView.AfterSelect event. Using a thread like this will peg a CPU core at 100% doing nothing.
private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(System.Object sender, 
    System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node==treeView1.Nodes[0]) //Or whatever condition you want
    {
        showProperties("label", e.Node.Tag);
    }
}

In Windows Forms almost all controls have a Tag property that can be used to store anything the application wants. You can store the ID value in the new node's tag :
TreeNode labelnode = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Label" + labelnum.ToString());
labelNode.Tag="1";


Thread thread = new Thread(() => Worker(labelnode, id));
thread.Start();

However, TreeNode sounds like a UI component, and UI components usually have "thread affinity"; touching it from a different thread will probably cause problems. You need to get back to the UI thread to update the UI, which is what control.Invoke(...) does in winforms. You may find it easier to use System.Windows.Forms.Timer, which invokes periodic callbacks for you on the UI thread.
